# C# Asyncronous Sockets Listener BeginReceive Callback is not fired all the time

Tags: c#, sockets, asynchronous, server, listener

I'm working on a Sockets Listener and have taken the code from this [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/asynchronous-server-socket-example) article.

This all works perfectly if the client is another Windows PC.
But the messages are coming from a Programmable Logic Controller over which I have no control and cannot debug.

Breakpoint is set (see below) and it always hits

```
public void AcceptCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{      
    // Signal the main thread to continue.  
    allDone.Set();

    // Get the socket that handles the client request.  
    Socket listener = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
    Socket handler = listener.EndAccept(ar);

    string remote = handler.RemoteEndPoint.ToString();

    // Create the state object.  
    StateObject state = new StateObject();

    state.workSocket = handler;

    //I set a breakpoint below and it's ALWAYS hit
    handler.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0, new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), state);
}
```

But this one is missed sometimes:

```
public void ReadCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    String content = String.Empty;
}
```

Can anyone think of why `BeginReceive` would be fired but not `ReadCallBack`?

Thanks

Comment: Hi Marty why don't you call EndReceive method inside your ReadCallback function
Socket socket = result.AsyncState as Socket;
bytesReceived = socket.EndReceive(result);

with EndReceive you ends a pending asynchronous read.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, yes, "int bytesRead = handler.EndReceive(ar);" is called in the ReadCallback, as per MSDN, but it sometimes doesn't get to that point.